# CloudKit per user usage

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

On the Apple Developer webpage for CloudKit (https://developer.apple.com/icloud/) it says that the first tier of usage is 0 users and 100MB of database storage. It also says that it is based on 2.5MB per user.

Does this mean that if one user goes over the 2.5MB amount it will then that costing or can one user use 3.5MB of storage and another use 1.5MB?

Thank you

Comment: The quota is an aggregate, so you can have one user using 100MB or 100 users each using 1MB

Comment: @Paulw11 Fantastic! Thank you for your help.